# how to select all rows in a table in the program without the user mouse selection of the rows?

Tags: swing

I am using JTable. Suppose I have a table which contains the following information -

```
        col1     col2    col3    col4
row1    ---      value1   ---    ---
row2    ---      value2   ---    ---
row3    ---      value3   ---    ---
row4    ---      value3   ---    ---
row5    ---      value1   ---    ---
row6    ---      value1   ---    ---
row7    ---      value2   ---    ---
row8    ---      value1   ---    ---
```

I need to copy the rows which have the value of col2 as "value1" into another table. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean inside your program.

```
int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
int columnCount = table.getColumnCount();
int row = 0; 

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    String value = table.getValueAt(i, 2);
    if (value.equals("value2") {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
            value = table.getValueAt(i, j);
            newTable.setValueAt(value, row, j): 
        }
        row++;
    }
}
```